# Sending formdata for file upload using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image by using form data with ajax. Though below line seems to be working fine and saving the image on my local machine.

```
<form ref='uploadForm' id='uploadForm' action='/tab10/uploadImage' method='post' encType="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="btn btn-default" name="file" />
<input type='submit' class="btn btn-default" value='Broadcast Image' />
</form>
```

But when instead of specifying action as a form attribute, i try to make the call using ajax, things didn't seem to be working fine.Below is the code that i am using to make the post API call using ajax.

HTML

```
<form ref='uploadForm' id='uploadForm' encType="multipart/form-data">
```

Jquery

```
$("form#uploadForm").submit(function (event) {
          //disable the default form submission
          event.preventDefault();
          var formData = $(this).serialize();
          console.log(formData);
          $.ajax({
              url: '/tab10/uploadImage',
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData,
              async: false,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function () {
                  alert('Form Submitted!');
              },
              error: function(){
                  alert("error in ajax form submission");
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
```

Below is the code i am using for saving the image.

```
exports.uploadImage = function(req, resp) {
var res = {};
let file = req.files.file;
file.mv('./images/image', function(err) {
if (err) {
  res.status = 500;
  res.message = err;
  // return res.status(500).send(err);
  return resp.send(res);
}
res.status = 200;
res.message = 'File uploaded!';
return resp.send(res);
});
};
```

When i checked the request data in my uploadimage function, it seems that in the request, parameter called "files" is not being send in the later case.

Comment: try to use full url.

Comment: FYI: `async: false,` *synchronous requests in the main thread are deprecated* - avoid it

Comment: `parameter called "files" is not being send in the later case` without seeing the form, it's a true mystery

Comment: but the request is being sent to the uploadimage function,so how will specifying the full url would be of any use. @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: oh ok @SrijanSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$("#uploadForm").submit(function () {
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      $.ajax({
          url: '/tab10/uploadImage',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function () {
              alert('Form Submitted!');
          },
          error: function(){
              alert("error in ajax form submission");
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: thanks man...was struggling with it for a long time....can you in brief try to explain the logic as to why was the one that i wrote not working?

Comment: new FormData(this); // you were not specifying which formData

Answer (score 3):

I think you have  to  create `FormData`, after you  can  append  the  file to the formData, add an ID to the input `<input type="file" class="btn btn-default" name="file" id="uploadFile"/>`

```
 $("form#uploadForm").submit(function (event) {
      //disable the default form submission
      event.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',$('#uploadFile')[0].files[0]);
      $.ajax({
          url: '/tab10/uploadImage',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function () {
              alert('Form Submitted!');
          },
          error: function(){
              alert("error in ajax form submission");
          }
      });

  });
```

Comment: this also doesn't seem to be working. in the working case this is the information that i get to use for moving the file:{ file: { name: 'images.png',
data: <Buffer >, encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/png',mv: [Function: mv] } } which  comes along in the req variable itself. however in this case we are getting only basic info like name of the image.

Comment: sorry i  edited my answer it should be `formData.append('file',$('#uploadFile')[0].files[0]);`  to  get the one  file.But in  some cases when you  want to  upload multiple files you  have  to  make  a loop

Answer (score 0):

Use this format to fire ajax.because file is multipart or jquery serialize() method not serialize multipart content,so we need to put it manual.

```
//get choosen file
var fileContent = new FormData();
fileContent.append("file",$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      enctype:"multipart/form-data",
       url: "/tab10/uploadImage",
       data: fileContent,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
        }
});
```